# dividing csv row numbers in columns separated by comma and space

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two types of csv files , both of which have several lines, but sometimes separated by a space and sometimes by a comma. for the comma case I don't find a problem adding them to a DataFrame, but I do have problem in the space case, I bring in my code in the following with the link to the files. the ex1.csv is separated by comma, but the ex2.csv is separated by space.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgQ59n47uloFzSPbIlS9RhRNfZ1p

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl as pyx
import numpy as np

x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
Rx=[]
Ry=[]
Rz=[]
atot=[]

t=[]

f = io.open(file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")

lines=f.readlines()

for i in lines:
    try:
        a=[i.strip('\n')]
        a1=[float(n) for n in a[0].split(',')]

            t.append(a1[1])
            x.append(a1[4])
            y.append(a1[3])
            z.append(a1[2])
            Rx.append(a1[7])
            Ry.append(a1[6])
            Rz.append(a1[5])

        except :
            a=[i.split('\n')]
            a1=[float(n) for n in a[0].split()]
            x.append(a1[3])
            y.append(a1[2])
            z.append(a1[1])
            Rx.append(a1[6])
            Ry.append(a1[5])
            Rz.append(a1[4])
```

Above: if the separators are comma, I get the error that 
'list' object has no attribute 'split'
and it's due to the fact that the a is read in this way :

```
a= [['\ufeff     -1.3053      2.2743     -5.0045      0.0121      0.1814     -0.0285      0.0000      0.0000',
  '']]
```

I add one point that beforehand I was separating the lines containing comma ( the lines after except in this way and it was separating well but It bugs me with error when trying to add it to a DataFrame:

```
            t.append(i.split()[0]);
            x.append(i.split()[3]);
            y.append(i.split()[2]);
            z.append(i.split()[1]);
            Rx.append(i.split()[6]);
            Ry.append(i.split()[5]);
            Rz.append(i.split()[4]);
```

adding the point that the addition to DataFrame is done in this way :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z, Rx, Ry, Rz)), columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'Rx' , 'Ry', 'Rz'])

for i in df1.columns:
    mylist+=(list(df1.loc[df1[i].argmax()]))
for i in df1.columns:
    mylist+=(list(df1.loc[df1[i].argmin()]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a really powerful method `pd.read_csv(...)`, that solves most of the hassle when reading all kinds of csv files. Maybe I missed some of the key problems thats prevent you from using `pd.read_csv(...)`, but the following code should serve as a proof of concept.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("ex1.csv", sep=",", header=None)
df1.columns = ["t", "atot", 'x', 'y', 'z', 'Rx', 'Ry', 'Rz']
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_csv("ex2.csv", sep=" ", header=None) 
df2 = df2.dropna(axis=1)  # Eliminate the columns that were created because of multiple spaces as separators
df2.columns = ["t", "atot", 'x', 'y', 'z', 'Rx', 'Ry', 'Rz']
print(df2)
```

I think that generally the csv corruption shouldn't serve as a justification for reading csv files line by line.

If you need separate columns later on as a list, you can create them them any time like this:

```
X = df2['x'].values.tolist()
Rx = df2['Rx'].values.tolist()
```

But, you should avoid using too much variables, as you might know already. Also, judging from your original code, it feels like you should spend some more time conquering the basics of Pandas, e.g.: [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html). There is a bit of learning curve, but it will save you a lot of pain later on.

Comment: Thank you so much ! just some questions : I had not the "atot" included in my question, but had used it exactly in my own code ! where did you see it ?

Comment: also : how did you discover that there are multiple spaces in ex2 ? did you have to run it once and get an error ?

Comment: I also added the way I opened the csv before, the io.open, that I found after long time searching on how to ! I added it just as more info

Comment: Also one problem : given the fact that I need each column of x,y,z ,.. later to process and write to separate files , how would I do that ?

Comment: Multiple spaces: You can use Excel to investigate the data, so you get the better idea about it. Column to list: See the edit.

Comment: I just ran it, and got this error : Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 46 fields in line 1038, saw 47, could you tell what is the problem ?

Comment: It just sounds like that in my files from line 1038, a space is added to a column that I could not say which, but from there on, it continues with a new trend, so it seems like that my code needs to be prepared for all undesireable surprises

Comment: You might want to find a reason for such a crappy input data. It shouldn't be that hard to read. Either way, welcome to the real world :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187584/discussion-between-fabiospaghetti-and-marjan-moderc).